# Tab model on a mobile device

Tags: mobile-web, tabs

I am in the process of exploring options to organize information in a page viewed on a mobile device. I am curios to know if there are any potential problems in using a tab model to organize information.

Answer (score 1):

Possible problem with tabs is "hidden tab", when limited number of tabs are displayed on a screen and no cues of other tabs presence, see image.
[image]

The problem occured on an Android 2.2 tablet, portrait orientation.

Answer (score 0):

When there's just too much information and that information is divisible, "Tabs" are just the
right UI patterns to implement.

Regarding implementation details, you face them when some information don't fills up entire Mobile's view-port height and that's also when using HTML+CSS+JS infused "Made for Mobile" framework and have put your hacks(UI) in lights of some requirements.